# Return number of elements

Tags: pointers, size

If I build a function with a introduced pointer like this:

```
int* c=new int[16];
```

And return it

```
return c;
```

How can I determine the size of c, (16), in my main(). I can't use sizeof because c isn't an array...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539/212869

Comment: @NickSlash THX for finding the dupe. That well explains about the problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: This is different question. The above SO links answer how to find the number of elements of array. And the question is - how to find the allocated object/array size by its pointer. I think the necessary value can be found by reading near bytes (pointer minus 2/4, etc.) which depends on malloc implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Since `c` is a pointer to int (that's what `int* c` means), what you get from `sizeof(c)` is exactly the size of the pointer to int. That is why `sizeof(c)/sizeof(int*)` gives you 1.

If you define `c` as array, not the pointer:

```
int c[16];
```

you'll get its size.

Comment: He said he gets `2` , so he might be on a 32-bit pointer and 16-bit int system (or 64 and 32 repectively)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yep, that's what I would think.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get number of elements in dynamically allocated array. It would work in this case:

```
int c[16];
int num_elements=sizeof(c)/sizeof(int);
```

In your case `sizeof(c)` is probably 4 (size of pointer).